# Moshi LocalDateTime adapter with multiple format

Tags: kotlin, java-time, moshi

By default, ThreeTenABP.LocalDateTime is converted to

`{"date":{"day":10,"month":4,"year":2018},"time":{"hour":3,"minute":34,"nano":115000000,"second":18}}`

I can write an adapter to support ISO date string `2018-04-10T03:45:26.009`

```
class LocalDateTimeAdapter {
    @ToJson
    fun toJson(value: LocalDateTime): String {
        return FORMATTER.format(value)
    }

    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(value: String): LocalDateTime {
        return FORMATTER.parse(value, LocalDateTime.FROM)
    }

    companion object {
        private val FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME
    }
}
```

How can I write an adapter which can support both format (fromJson)

- `{"date":{"day":10,"month":4,"year":2018},"time":{"hour":3,"minute":34,"nano":115000000,"second":18}}`
- `2018-04-10T03:45:26.009`

Beside identifying which the format is used in `fromJson`, I am curious how Moshi internally perform toJson/fromJson for LocalDateTime

Comment: is this a Joda time LocalDateTime or the java.time one?

Comment: @EricCochran java.time, I am actually using ThreeTenABP which is a JSR-310 backport.

Comment: when your JSON is coming in, do you know what format it is going to be?
like `class Foo { LocalDateTime usesFormat1; }` and `class Bar { LocalDateTime usesFormat2; }`

or, do you not know and need to handle either format for all your uses of LocalDateTime?

Comment: @EricCochran I won't know the expected format, so the adapter needs a mechanism to detect/guest the format.

Comment:  then Jesse's answer is perfect for you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You’ll need to use `JsonReader.peek()` to determine the format of the incoming JSON, and then take action accordingly.

First install an adapter that converts `LocalDateTime` to a string. That adapter should use a qualifier annotation.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JsonQualifier
@interface DateString {
}
```

Next create the string adapter. It should be straightforward, and might delegate to Moshi’s built-in Rfc3339DateJsonAdapter.

```
public final class LocalDateAsStringAdapter {
  @ToJson String toJson(@DateString LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
    ...
  }

  @FromJson @DateString LocalDateTime fromJson(String string) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Finally create an adapter that delegates either to Moshi’s built in adapter (that one will use `{...}`) or to your string adapter. This one prefers the string format, but you can do what you like.

```
public final class MultipleFormatsDateAdapter {
  @ToJson void toJson(JsonWriter writer, LocalDateTime value,
      @DateString JsonAdapter<LocalDateTime> stringAdapter) throws IOException {
    stringAdapter.toJson(writer, value);
  }

  @FromJson LocalDateTime fromJson(JsonReader reader, @DateString JsonAdapter<LocalDateTime> stringAdapter,
      JsonAdapter<LocalDateTime> defaultAdapter) throws IOException {
    if (reader.peek() == JsonReader.Token.STRING) {
      return stringAdapter.fromJson(reader);
    } else {
      return defaultAdapter.fromJson(reader);
    }
  }
}
```

This works because Moshi lets you declare multiple `JsonAdapter` arguments to the `@ToJson` and `@FromJson` methods, and these arguments may be annotated.

It also relies on the way this feature works if the types are the same. Here we’re making a `JsonAdapter<LocalDateTime>` by delegating to another `JsonAdapter<LocalDateTime>`. When the types are the same Moshi uses its `nextAdapter()` feature for composition.

Comment: Thank for showing the way to use JsonQualifier and accessing defaultAdapter. I have documented the problem and solution: https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/moshi-datetime-adapter-with-multiple-format-support/